# rosmake openni_camera gives an error

Tags: openni, camera, rosmake, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i had to reinstall my system. Before, i made a backup of my ros workspace.

After installing ros, i tried my old launch files and they don't work. I solved some errors already.
But, if i try to build openni_camera with "rosmake openni_camera" i get an error:

`make[2]: execvp: cfg/OpenNIUnstable.cfg: Permission denied 
  make[2]: *** [cfg/cpp/openni_camera/OpenNIUnstableConfig.h] Error 127
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ROSBUILD_gencfg_cpp.dir/all] Error 2`

Can somebody gives me a hint to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49716/rosmake-openni_camera-gives-an-error/) by [Schlangenmensch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3720/schlangenmensch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the fast answer. But the problem was the follow:

I had an old openni_camera stack as backup in my workspace, because I changed there something. And now ROS tried to compile the older version from my workspace. So, I moved it away from my workspace an I am using the actual openni_camera stack now. And it works fine ;)

---

Originally posted by [Schlangenmensch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3720/schlangenmensch/) with karma: 16 on 2012-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess when restoring your system backup, you did not transfer ownership or permissions correctly.

You'd probably want to do something like:

```
sudo chown -R mynewuser ros_workspace
```

and maybe also

```
sudo chmod -R u+rwX ros_workspace
```

Also, you should run `make clean` on each of the packages in the workspace or remove the build/ directories as cmake might have cached directories there.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3